# Taking a git diff and creating a new branch in different repo

Tags: git, github

We two friends are working on a project:

I have made some local changes in my project, which still needs to be committed.
when i take a git diff it lists out the difference between my local repo and staging area.

My other friend is working on the same project and want to add the git diff in my local repo to his own local repo as a different branch.

What is the way to do this ?

Comment: Best solution is to push your changes to remote origin and he pulls from remote. Is there something preventing you from doing this?

Comment: no this is an option, we just wanted to know if there is some other way to do it.
for this we can stash the change and then apply those changes to another branch - > then push -> and then he pulls.
is there any other way to do this ?
P.S current branch is master

Comment: keep everything in branches which you push and pull to the remote.  You can also merge changes into master as you wish.  This is all part of the basics of using a dvcs like git.

Comment: You can also use `git format-patch` to prepare your changes as a patch and `git am` to apply those changes. But your changes should still be committed locally before doing this. It's mostly useful if the developer who prepared the commits doesn't have commit permissions on the remote repository.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922094/taking-a-git-diff-and-creating-a-new-branch-in-different-repo/24922587#comment38724313_24922094), the typical way to share changes is via pushes and fetches to remote repos, and pull requests.

*However*, if you really want to use diffs as patches instead, then you can send to your friend the diff/patch as a file (or copy and paste into an email or instant messaging, if you're okay with the security of those channels...or lack thereof). Your friend can then attempt to apply the patch to his own local branch.

#### What you need to do

```
git diff > diff.patch
```

Send `diff.patch` to your friend.

#### What your friend needs to do

```
git apply diff.patch
```

#### Documentation

- [git-apply(1) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply)
- [Pro Git: § 5.3 Distributed Git - Maintaining a Project - Applying Patches from E-mail](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#Applying-Patches-from-E-mail)

Answer (score 0):

`git apply` is the command you're looking for. **However:**

> I have made some local changes in my project, *which still needs to be committed.*

The standard git advice is "commit early, commit often," and it's very good advice. I'd recommend getting comfortable working with commits (reordering them, editing them, squashing them, and pushing them around). Once you've committed changes, git will essentially never lose your work. Commands like `git reflog` can do magic to get your commits back. But many commands (`reset`, `checkout`) can pave over your uncommitted work and ruin your day. And of course, you have to have commits to push your changes over the network, as others have suggested.